# FIND_LIBRARY does not find existing libraries

Tags: qt, cmake

In the function `findQt4.cmake`:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY_RELEASE
                   NAMES QtCore QtCore4
                   HINTS ${QT_LIBRARY_DIR_TMP}
          )
```

if I print:

```
MESSAGE("HINT PATH " ${QT_LIBRARY_DIR_TMP})
```

I will get:

```
~/dev/Libraries/Qt4.8.0/lib
```

In this directory there are: `~/dev/Libraries/Qt4.8.0/lib$ ls -all libQtCore*`

I got:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc abc     950 Nov 30 13:08 libQtCore.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc abc     942 Nov 30 13:07 libQtCore.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc      18 Nov 30 13:07 libQtCore.so -> libQtCore.so.4.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc      18 Nov 30 13:08 libQtCore.so.4 -> libQtCore.so.4.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc      18 Nov 30 13:08 libQtCore.so.4.8 -> libQtCore.so.4.8.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 abc abc 2697932 Nov 30 13:08 libQtCore.so.4.8.0
```

But why the `FIND_LIBRARY` function return: `QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY_RELEASE = NOT FOUND?`

Even, there is no result if I do like this:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY_RELEASE
                       NAMES libQtCore.so
                       HINTS ${QT_LIBRARY_DIR_TMP}
              )
```

Comment: Did you try to strace your cmake run? On an Out-Of-Source build, this would be "cd build ; strace cmake .." I'm a fan of vim, so I pipe the output to it: "cd build ; strace cmake .. 2>&1 | gview -" In the output you can see, which paths are searched (openat() calls here)

Comment: could you tell us why you are fumbling in the findQt4.cmake file? You could simply use 

find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)

include(${QT_USE_FILE})
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

to set up qt for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `find_library()` you can use [`find_package()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3afind_package). This is the [common way](http://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects) for Qt with CMake.

```
# Find Qt package
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED) 

include(${QT_USE_FILE}) # Add and run Qt CMake modules
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS}) # Add definitions (if required)

# And later put all together
add_executable( ... )
target_link_libraries( ... ${QT_LIBRARIES}) # Link Qt libraries
```